# Convert array of strings to List<string>

Tags: c#, c#-2.0

I've seen examples of this done using `.ToList()` on array types, this seems to be available only [in .Net 3.5+](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb342261.aspx). I'm working with .NET Framework 2.0 on an ASP.NET project that can't be upgraded at this time, so I was wondering: is there another solution? One that is more elegant than looping through the array and adding each element to this List (which is no problem; I'm just wondering if there is a better solution for learning purposes)?

```csharp
string[] arr = { "Alpha", "Beta", "Gamma" };

List<string> openItems = new List<string>();

foreach (string arrItem in arr)
{
    openItems.Add(arrItem);
}
```

If I have to do it this way, is there a way to deallocate the lingering array from memory after I copy it into my list?

Comment: Don't worry about cleaning up your `arr`, the garbage collector will do a lot better job of that than you will.

Comment: You specifically.  And me.  In fact, I think only Jon Skeet is allowed to do his own garbage collection.

Comment: @MikeChristensen Couldn't resist upvoting that for the Jon Skeet comment. lol

Answer (score 497, accepted):

Just use [this constructor](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fkbw11z0(v=vs.110).aspx) of `List<T>`. It accepts any `IEnumerable<T>` as an argument.

```csharp
string[] arr = ...
List<string> list = new List<string>(arr);
```

Answer (score 41):

From .Net 3.5 you can use LINQ extension method that (sometimes) makes code flow a bit better.

Usage looks like this:

```
using System.Linq; 

// ...

public void My()
{
    var myArray = new[] { "abc", "123", "zyx" };
    List<string> myList = myArray.ToList();
}
```

PS. There's also `ToArray()` method that works in other way.

Comment: @quest4truth - Visual Studio version has nothing to do with it. It will work in 2022 and VS Code as well as long as you have .NET with Linq (+ `using System.Ling` there.