# How to copy string of array to list<string>?

Tags: c#, string, winforms, list

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Convert array of strings to List<string>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10129419/convert-array-of-strings-to-liststring)

I am new to C# 
 How to copy entire string of array to List?

i have tried this but i didn't get any solution.

```
 List<string> lstArray  = strArray.toList<string>;

    or           
 List<string> lstArray = new List<string>();
 strArray.copyTo(lstArray,0);
```

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Pass string array in list [constructor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fkbw11z0%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

```
List<string> yourList = new List<string>(strArray);
```

The reason your first line didn't work was because you are not using the correct syntax. So instead of

```
List<string> lstArray  = strArray.toList<string>;
```

Use

```
List<string> lstArray = strArray.ToList<string>();
```

or

```
List<string> lstArray = strArray.ToList(); // with less keystrokes, since the array is of type string.
```

For the 2nd option where you are trying to use Array.CopyTo, it works with array types, not generic list. You are probably getting the error.

> The best overloaded method match for
>   'System.Array.CopyTo(System.Array, int)' has some invalid arguments

Since it expects an array and you are passing a generic list.

Comment: you should ans y his solution didnt work

Comment: @Fake.It.Til.U.Make.It, thanks, I was actually doing that :)

Comment: thankQ for providing now it's works fine @Habib