# Convert custom delimited string to List<myClass>?

Tags: c#, linq

How do I turn this:

```
string x = "key:value|key:value|key:value|key:value";
```

into this?

```
List<myClass> listObj;
```

myClass definition:

```
public class myClass
{
    public string keyName { get; set; }
    public string keyValue { get; set; }
}
```

There has to be a way to do it using LINQ or something :)
thanks in advance!

*** NOTE *** 
I should add I know how to do this splitting it and looping through it, but there has to be a better way :)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Convert array of strings to List<string>](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10129419/convert-array-of-strings-to-liststring)

Comment: You can use Dictionary<string,string>, and String.Split() method..

Comment: Not a duplicate - the other article is a single string array. My question is about having a list within a list (multidimensional).

Comment: @egrunin, it's not a duplicate of that question, as the OP really has a string (with a faked array of keyvaluepair's inside it). not an array of strings. Perhaps we need to change the title, though I'm not sure how to refer to that.

Comment: Retracted close vote.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This will require separate `ToList()` call, but I like query syntax for its declarative nature:

```
from s in x.Split('|')
let parts = s.Split(':')
select new myClass { 
    keyName = parts[0], 
    keyValue = parts[1] 
}
```

Or you can use fluent syntax:

```
x.Split('|')
 .Select(s => {
    var parts = s.Split(':');
    return new myClass { 
        keyName = parts[0], 
        keyValue = parts[1] 
    };
 }).ToList()
```

Answer (score 0):

Do this if you prefer to use your custom class instead of Dictionary

```
 var result = from y in x.Split('|')
             let obj = y.Split(':')
             select new myClass{keyName = obj[0], keyValue = obj[1]};

 var list = result.ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, since you really wanted to avoid splitting and looping...

```
public List<MyClass> Parse(string base, string workingName, string workingValue,
                           bool processingName = true, 
                           List<MyClass> workingList = null, int index = 0)
{
    if (workingList == null)
        workingList = new List<MyClass>();

    if (index >= base.Length)
    {
        return workingList;
    }
    if (base[index] = '|')
    {
        workingList.Add(new MyClass { keyName = workingName, keyValue = workingValue });
        return Parse(base, "", "", true, workingList, index + 1);
    }
    else if (base[index] = ':')
    {
        return Parse(base, workingName, "", false, workingList, index + 1);
    }
    else if (processingName)
    {
        return Parse(base, workingName + base[index], "", processingName, workingList, index + 1);
    }
    else
    {
        return Parse(base, workingName, workingValue + base[index], processingName, workingList, index + 1);
    }
}
```

But please, for the love of whatever you hold dear, don't do anything even remotely resembling that (and yes, this is untested, hand-written code, so there are probably errors - just making a joke about avoiding things).