# Convert ArrayOfString to List<string> in C# for Windows Phone 7

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

I have an error "Cannot implicitly convert type "CorrespondingBall.MyCloudService.ArrayOfString' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List". Does anyone know how can I solved it? I have read up on [Convert array of strings to List<string>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10129419/convert-array-of-strings-to-liststring), but I do not understand and implement it. My codes are below.

```
ServiceSoapClient client = new ServiceSoapClient();

List<string> objectiveList = new List<string>();

client.getObjectiveCompleted += new EventHandler<getObjectiveCompletedEventArgs>(getObjectiveCompletedHandler);
client.getObjectiveAsync();
```

I received the error for

```
private void getObjectiveCompletedHandler(object sender, getObjectiveCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        objectiveList = e.Result;
    }
```

Comment: I don't know what a `CorrespondingBall.MyCloudService.ArrayOfString` is, but can you use a foreach and add them to the list one by one?

Comment: Hi @Jonesy, I am using a web service, MyCloudService and the application name is CorrespondingBall.

Comment: Are you return `List<string>` from your service method? or `string[]`? what is your web service (WCF, ASMX..)? are you adding service reference or web reference?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Supposing e.Result is an array of string you can do it like this

```
private void getObjectiveCompletedHandler(object sender, getObjectiveCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
      List<string> namesList = new List<string>();

      foreach (string name in e.Result)
       {
        namesList.Add(name);
       }
    }
```

Comment: This is ofchurs depending if e.Result is really returning array. If not then you should change your question to how to return an array from your cloud service

Comment: Hi @TheProvost, it is returning a list.

Comment: If its returning a list as you say it does. then  objectiveList = e.Result;
would not have triggered an error. Im sure the problem is with sending the correct object type rather than conversion

Answer (score 4):

If ArrayOfString is truly a basic `array` of `string` types, you can do the following:

```
    string[] names = { "John", "Doe" };

    List<string> namesList = new List<string>(names);

    // OR

    List<string> namesList2 = new List<string>();

    foreach (string name in names)
    {
        namesList2.Add(name);
    }
```

Comment: Hi @Inisheer, what if the values are from database?

Comment: @LiuJiaHui It doesn't matter the source of the data. More important is how you are retrieving and storing that data in your code. You will need to provide additional code in order to provide a more detailed solution.